# Restrict Landscape orientation in subview:iPad

Tags: ios, ipad, orientation, subview, restrict

I am using the following code to keep the launch and splash screens in portrait mode.In all other views all orientations are allowed.

```
- (NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window
{       
if (launchView)          
{              
return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;     
  }           
 return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;              
}
```

I am using an Imageview called launchView as the splash screen that displays just after the launch screen.The above code restricts all orientations other than portrait mode in Iphone and is working totally fine.But when it comes to ipad it goes wrong and shows landscape orientation too. Can anybody help me to understand where I am making mistake?

When I have checked this code is working in iPad but still it shows landscape orientation.

Answer (score 1):

Update your info.plist file and add following parameters in it.

[image]

This may help you...